# Problema no Google Maps JavaScript API V3 com WebApp em MVC

Tags: javascript, html5, google-maps, mvc

Quero fazer com que um simples Mapa apareça quando o usuário clicar no (Menu>Localizar), o problema é que o controlador recebe os dados e me envia e não retorna o Mapa.

Estou usando em meu projeto, padrão MVC.

> O código, disponibilizei no [repositório do aplicativo.](https://github.com/icejack/boasaude)

Comment: Você se refere ao item em vermelho na imagem da direita? Ela não tem nenhuma relação com o Google maps.

Comment: @bfavaretto Coloquei essa imagem apenas para mostrar que os arquivos são carregados. Aquele item em vermelho não está sendo o problema. Meu problema é o carregamento do mapa.

Comment: Então, fica difícil ajudar com essas informações. A gente teria que olhar todo o seu código em detalhes até achar o problema. Você conseguiria isolar o problema e postar um exemplo pequeno que reproduza o que está ocorrendo?

Comment: @bfavaretto O que você acha, vou editar o que postei isolando apenas o problema reduzindo os códigos e postando eles aqui. Ok!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Então, baseado no arquivo que está no seu [GitHub](https://github.com/icejack/boasaude/blob/master/assets/js/controllers/MapaController.js) em ' boasaude / assets / js / controllers / MapaController.js',

Percebi que na linha 17

> 'google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);'

Depis de baixar o ser código fiz a seguinte alteração:
Troquei a linha 17 por uma chamada a função e ficaou assim:

> "initialize();"

**Obs.: Porque não funciona? a janela (window) já está carregada por isso o "initialize" do addDomListener não fazia a função iniciar.**

Mesmo assim o mapa não apareceu.... mas notei que conteúdo dentro da  que carrega o mapa tinha mudado...

Fiz um teste colocando altura e largura e trocando o código que estava em index.html, ficando assim:

```
<style>
         html, body, #map-canvas {
          /*height: 100%;  Código antigo */
          height: 600px; /* Novo */
          width: 600px; /* Novo */
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 0px
         }
</style>
```

E pronto... o mapa apareceu.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: fiz o que você falou e resolveu! Obg